# adverb translation

Tags: adverb

I am trying to get a German translation of the following adverbs:

Unfathomably
Terribly

I am told that the suffix "lich" would be added to both("unergrundlich" and "schrecklich") however I do not know if this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, both of those are real words in the dictionary (see [unergründlich](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/unergr%C3%BCndlich.html)
 and [schrecklich](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=schrecklich) in Linguee), so yes, that is correct.